# Set a value for <form: input> in Spring's form tag library

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc

How can I possibly set a value for a form input field using the form tag library in Spring MVC shown below even if it has no value attribute and is not accepted according to form tld?

```
<form:input path ="name" id="name" cssStyle="display: none"/>
```

Not based on requirement:

```
<input type="hidden" id="name" value="Raven"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `<form:input>`? It's for binding to beans.

You can use a regular `<input>` element ;)

If you want to set its value:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<c:set var="name" value="Raven" />

<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<c:out value='${name}' />" />
```

Comment: Im actually binding the form input in a form to its domain that is why I want to know how could I set a value to itself. Thank you